# Nextjs 13: getStaticProps called in the browser

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

i have a nextjs 13 application, using **app** directory instead of **pages**, all pages are statically generated at build time, data fetched from an external api. [image]

and everything is fine, when the app is deployed into the production server, it still calls the api, even though the page is completely static

```
const seeds = await getSeeds();
  const apps = await getAllApps();
  const numberOfCategories = (() => {
    const { categories } = seeds;
    const mainCategories = Object.keys(categories);
    const subCategories = Object.values(categories).flat();
    return mainCategories.length + subCategories.length;
  })();
  const { countriesSize, citiesSize } = (() => {
    const { locations } = seeds;
    const countries = Object.keys(locations);
    const cities = Object.values(locations).flat();
    return { countriesSize: countries.length, citiesSize: cities.length };
  })();
```

using axios for api calls

what could be the issue in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using **css-in-js** library, which forced me to use `'use-client'` and made the data fetching to occur on the client-side, the solution is to swap the **css-in-js** library with pure css/modules, and design a better hierarchy of components.